# WPF datagrid fire sorting event in code

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some code which listens to the "sorting"-event of a datagrid to be able to add a custom sorter...

I add this when the datagrid has loaded.

```
grid.Sorting += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var column = (DataGridCustomTextColumn) args.Column;



                //i do some custom checking based on column to get the right comparer
                //i have different comparers for different columns. I also handle the sort direction
                //in my comparer

                // prevent the built-in sort from sorting
                args.Handled = true;

                var direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    ? ListSortDirection.Ascending
                    : ListSortDirection.Descending;

                //set the sort order on the column
                column.SortDirection = direction;

                //use a ListCollectionView to do the sort.
                var lcv = (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.ItemsSource);

                //this is my custom sorter it just derives from IComparer and has a few properties
                //you could just apply the comparer but i needed to do a few extra bits and pieces
                var comparer = new DataGridCommonSort(column.RealDataType, column.SortMemberPath, direction);

                //apply the sort
                lcv.CustomSort = comparer;

            };
```

The problem is that this handler gets only called when I click the columnheader.
But I need a way to initialy fire this event that the data gets sorted

Any ideas?
I tried something like:

```
ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(c.SortMemberPath, ListSortDirection.Descending));
            dataView.Refresh();
```

but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Changing the DefaultView is correct and this works for me doing a quick test. Do you set dataGrid.ItemsSource directly to your data or a different collectionview? Are you sure it is set before calling GetDefaultView? Are you sure c.SortMemberPath is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the event handler as a (nonanonymous) method:

```
private void grid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs args)
{
    //same code as before...
}
```

...and simply call it after you have set the `ItemsSource` property:

```
grid_Sorting(grid, new DataGridSortingEventArgs(grid.Columns[0])); //sort by the first column
```